# Is there any way to recognize keywords from users' input texts in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile-application

I want to create a mobile application via android studio by which I ask a question from the user, then users should type their answer in the input box. What I want is, my application can recognize the keywords from the input text and matches that with the keyword list that I have already defined during the coding time. Then it gives a feedback (a piece of text or a sound track) according to the keywords.
fore example the question is: Which city do you like to live in?
possible answer: I like to live in a **crowded** city.
Application recognizes the keyword "Crowded" and shows the corresponding text or plays corresponding sound track.

Now my question is, is there any way to recognize keywords from users' input texts in Android?

Comment: do you want the recognition to happen while the user is writing or after submitting the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I've only used [recognition per key](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands), to stop using the letter ñ in my `EditTexts`, since you want a whole word, you could have a list of words to recognize, add a `TextWatcher` to your `EditText` then when you are on the `afterTextChanged()` method, you could check if EditText.getText() has a word in that list using regex.

Some scratch code:

```
 editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                    
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                   // get the text that has been inputted 
                   String val = editText.getText().toString()
                   // search that text using regex or other method
                   if(textIsInList(val))
                   {
                     playSound()
                   }
                }
```